# facebook graph request using swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, graph, sdk

I am trying to implement a facebook graph request just as described on their developer´s doc page (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/graph). Xcode 10.2.1, swift 5.

But I keep getting the following error:

> Contextual closure type '(GraphRequestConnection?, Any?, Error?) -> Void' expects 3 arguments, but 2 were used in closure body

I have done a lot of research and tried to fill in several arguments but I simply cannot figure out what the missing third argument might be.

```
import FBSDKCoreKit

let connection = GraphRequestConnection()
connection.add(GraphRequest(graphPath: "/me")) { httpResponse, result in
    switch result {
        case .success(let response):
        print ("Graph Request succeeded: \(resonse)")

        case .failed (let error):
            print ("Graph Request failed: \(error)")
    }
}
connection.start()
```

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I got the same behavior. I am not that experienced in Swift and the Facebook Graph API and I'm not sure if it is a good solution but, currently (until I find a better solution), for me works:

```
connection.add(GraphRequest(graphPath: "/me", parameters: ["fields":"email"])) { httpResponse, result, error   in
    if error != nil {
        NSLog(error.debugDescription)
        return
    }

    // Handle vars
    if let result = result as? [String:String],
        let email: String = result["email"],
        let fbId: String = result["id"] {

        // internal usage of the email
        self.userService.loginWithFacebookMail(facebookMail: email)

    }

}
```

Comment: do we have to add the connection.start() at the end to start the request ?

Comment: Yes! connection.start() is required.

Answer (score 0):

I made an improvement of the last answer. If you are requesting parameters such as "location {location {country_code}}", you will have a json with more than 1 level. For this, it is necessary to cast the result to [String: Any] because if you do not, you will get a nil.

```
connection.add(GraphRequest(graphPath: "/me", parameters: ["fields":"email,location{location{country_code}}"])) { httpResponse, result, error   in
    if error != nil {
        NSLog(error.debugDescription)
        return
    }

    if let result = result as? [String:Any],
     let email = result["email"] as? String {
        if let location_data = result["location"] as? [String: Any],
         let location = location_data["location"] as? [String: Any],
         let countryCode = location["country_code"] as? String {
            country = countryCode
        }
     }
}
```